# Making fixed format file

Tags: java, string, file, java-io

I have an input file with 50000 rows. It is suppossed to be fixed format (30 chars). 
But the inputs are strings.

e.g.

```
This is line one. 
This is line one and complete.
This is line empty.
```

First line is 17 characters. Second line is 30 characters. Third line is 20 characters.

In my input file, as soon as the line gets over, the new line character is present.

However, I want the new line character exactly at the 31st position. Thus if a line is shorter then 30 characters, spaces should be padded to make it 30 chars line.

How to do this for this huge input file ?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: 50,000*30=1,500,000, I wouldn't consider this as a huge file and so I will read everything into memory first.

Comment: Are you asking how to pad the rows? how to read the file? the question is not so clear

Comment: You can't pad your input as you are only reading it, not writing it, nor would you want to.  You might want to pad your output to suit a particular format. Its not clear what you are trying to do or why.

Comment: I am using a spring batch program to read the input. Fixed format. But since my input file is not fixed format. I want to convert it into a fixed format file (30 char per line). How to achieve that with above file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it enough to [pad the string](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#rightPad%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20char%29)?